# Unable to create a folder in dropbox using Php API Dropbox using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dropbox-api

While User uploads the files, the folder should be automatically created in the dropbox with the username as folder name. and then after the files that were uploaded by the user should be saved in that folder. 
**Error thrown:**
"
Error: Resource at uri: https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/sweety could not be found."

The code is

```
// Upload
$wpschunks = explode("/",$wpsdbTmpFile);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wpschunks); $i++) {
    $c = $i;
}
global $current_user;
$wpuserid = $current_user->data->ID;
$wpusername = $current_user->data->user_login;
$newfoldername = $wpusername;

// echo trim($wpsdb_path,'/').' //\\ ';
$folderMetadata = $dropbox->getMetaData(trim($wpsdb_path, '/') . '/' . $newfoldername, true);

if (!$folderMetadata['is_dir']) {
    $dropbox->CreateFolder(trim($wpsdb_path, '/') . '/' . $newfoldername, "dropbox");
    if ( !$dropbox->putFile(trim($wpsdb_path,'/').'/'.$newfoldername.'/'.$wpschunks[$c], $wpstmpFile,"dropbox") ) {
        throw new Exception(__('ERROR! Upload Failed.','simpleDbUpload'));
    }
    if($wpsdb_delete_file == "True") {
        if (isset($wpsdbTmpFile) && file_exists($wpsdbTmpFile)) {
            unlink($wpsdbTmpFile);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
When we create the blank folder manually in dropbox and then delete it and then if we try to upload the files the folder is create automatically(using this code) and the files also get uploaded.

Comment: What library and what version are you using? I don't believe that the latest version of the official Dropbox PHP SDK should raise an error when the path you're requesting metadata of doesn't exist.

Comment: I am using the api version of 2010.... And I am using the "Simple Dropbox" Plugin in wordpress which i m modifying according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "api version of 2010" means. :-) I don't know what library the Wordpress plugin is based on, but it looks like in this one, an error is raised when you request the metadata of a path that doesn't exist. I don't see why this is a problem... just handle the error and continue?

As an alternative, you could just not create the folder at all. Folders are implicitly created in Dropbox when you upload files into them. So you could just go straight to the `$dropbox->putFile()` call and skip checking for the folder and creating it if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But i have requirement, while uploading the files by any user, folder will be created of username and then in that folder, files will be uploaded in drop box. Please provide me the solution as my requirement.

Comment: As I said, you don't have to explicitly create the folder. You can just start adding files to it.